# How to compare enum array values and console input?

Tags: arrays, .net, enums

How to check is there a value which user enter from console.

I've got five enum values:

```
enum Fruits
{
    apple = 1,
    orange,
    banana,
    chery,
    kiwi
}
```

And created an array of those values:

```
Array arrayFruits = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Fruits));
```

The follow code below:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter plant");
string plantNotLow = Console.ReadLine();
string plant = plantNotLow.ToLower();

object element = Enum.Parse(typeof(Fruits), plant);
Fruits fruit = (Fruits)element;

Array arrayFruits = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Fruits));

for (int i = 0; i < arrayFruits.Length; i++)
{
    if(arrayFruits.GetValue(i) == element)
    {

    }
}
```

E.g. user enter "apple", how to enter in if-block?

Comment: To test for apple specifically: `if (element == Fruits.apple)`. - not sure if that's what you mean. Note that `arrayFruits` is actually a `Fruits[]` - casting it to that makes it much easier to work with

Comment: When I enter to console "apple" it should comparing with array of enum like Enum type, or Object type ? or I think in wrong way...?

Comment: I can't parse that sentence; I might be able to help, but I first need to understand what you're trying to do. If you want to compare to each defined enum value, then like I said: cast the array to `Fruits[]`, then just test `thatTypedArray[i]==fruit` - or use `Array.IndexOf`, etc

Comment: I mean, why my code is wrong her  if((arrayFruits.GetValue(i) == element) ? Because I need to compare user-input with any elements of enum_Array, and if there exist e,g, apple I can pass to if-block code

Comment: Because `==` is complex and doesn't do what you think here, because you're using `object`. Note that `.Equals` instead of `==` should work, but - and I keep saying this - casting the array to `Fruits[]` will also work. The `==` on `object` is very different to the `==` between two enums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem here is the `==` in this line:

```cs
if(arrayFruits.GetValue(i) == element)
```

Specifically, because `arrayFruits` is `Array` rather than `Fruits[]`, this is an `object ==` test, which is a reference comparison against a freshly boxed value, which will never return true (it is reference equality).

Solutions:

1. cast the array to `Fruits[]` and use `typedArray[i] == fruit` - this then compares two enums using integer equality, or
2. use `Equals` instead of `==` when dealing with `object`

The first option is by far the better option.

Answer (score 0):

cast to Fruits:

```
if ((Fruits)arrayFruits.GetValue(i) == (Fruits)element)
```

Comment: Note that this involves a box and unbox/type-check, and an indirect vector lookup (it is hard to explain what this means without going into some slightly more advanced concepts, but - "not great"). If possible, you should prefer to cast the array itself, once, which then avoids all this mess.